# add src/it/java as test folder in intellij when opening project as pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, intellij-idea

I have a new test fodler called src/it/java (for integration tests).
I added this to my pom.xml (in my simple example app)

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-test-source</id>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>src/it/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

However when i open my project (by opening the pom.xml in intellij) in intellij then src/it/java is not regarded by it as a source folder.

what should I put in my pom.xml to have intellij recognize src/it/java as a source folder

thanks

Comment: i saw this thread http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-27176?projectKey=IDEA&query=build-helper-maven-plugin with this recommendation "Aha, found an easy workaround - execute the plugin on the generate-sources phase instead of generate-test-sources and everything seems to work fine." i tried it with no success.  i'm using intellij 10.5.2 community edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the paths that are configured by plug-ins you should run **Generate Sources and Update Folders**, [see the FAQ](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Maven_FAQ).

Comment: thanks this worked.  is there a solution to the problem that when i right click src/it/java or src/test/java and try to run its tests in intellij its running ALL tests and not just tests under this folder?